# VMWare Workstation modal dialogs too wide

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, vmware-workstation

I have a dual-monitor setup running under Windows 10. I recently upgraded from VMWare Workstation 14 to 15. All of a sudden, I am seeing all modal dialogs having a width longer than both my monitors combined. I never had this problem on Workstation 14.

Is anyone else seeing this problem? Is it a known bug? Is there a workaround or configuration option I should be looking at?

The left monitor is 1920x1080 with a scaling factor of 100%. The right monitor is 3840x2160 with a scaling factor of 150%. This issue happens regardless of which monitor Workstation is running on.

To reproduce the problem click on "Revert this virtual machine to snapshot". Here is what I see:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I would report the issue to VMWare,  if Workstation is running on either monitor, does this behavior happen?

Comment: @Ramhound This issue happens regardless of which monitor I am running Workstation on.

Comment: Please provide all relevant information in the question body

Comment: @Ramhound Done. Will delete this comment in a day or two.

Comment: does it happen if both monitors are set to 100% scaling?  Does it happen if you're only using one of the monitors?  To me, it looks like a bug with Windows not being able to deal with the resolution and/or scaling differences between the 2 monitors.   I have several dual monitor and triple monitor environments with Workstation and don't see this behavior, but the monitors have identical resolutions.

Comment: @essjae I get this behavior even if both monitors are set to 100% scaling. Are you using Workstation 15 Pro?

Comment: Yes, Workstation 15 pro.

Comment: [This thread](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/603015) has an update as of March 2019: they think they found the problematic code but no ETA on a fix yet.